# Объединение элементов List

Tags: java, коллекции

На вход получаю некий List

```
@Override
public List transformList(List list) {
return list;
}
```

если что это переопределенный метод ResultTransformer()
структура получаемого List следующая:

```
List {{1, 2, 3, List {a, b, c}, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, List {d, e, f}, 5, 6, 7}}
```

Состоит из двух элементов, данные повторяются, внутри каждого элемента еще один List где данные уже пересекаться не будут

Есть-ли какое-то решение чтобы привести этот List к виду:

```
List {1, 2, 3, List {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}, 5, 6, 7}
```

Comment: совершенно непонятно, что вы хотите

Comment: непонятно, по какому правилу вы хотите получить результирующий лист из входного

Comment: если бы я знал по какому правилу, я бы вопрос и не задавал :) я написал какой результат прилетает и какой хотелось бы видеть, если это невозможно, значит будем копать как-то иначе

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете вот этим `{a, b, c}` в результирующем `List`? это какой-то объект или что? какого типа у вас элементы исходного `List` и результата?

Comment: [{"id":2,"title":"test title","username":"Name","tags":[{"id":1,"name":"java","description":"java the best"}],"reputationCount":12,"viewCount":1,"countAnswer":0,"countValuable":1,"persistDateTime":"2020-05-06T17:31:31"},{"id":2,"title":"test title","username":"Name","tags":[{"id":2,"name":"sql","description":"i love sql"}],"reputationCount":12,"viewCount":1,"countAnswer":0,"countValuable":1,"persistDateTime":"2020-05-06T17:31:31"} вот, если вам это как-то поможет, на выходе имеем вот такой JSON

Comment: хотелось бы привести его к виду:  [{"id":2,"title":"test title","username":"Name","tags":[{"id":1,"name":"java","description":"java the best"},{"id":2,"name":"sql","description":"i love sql"}],"reputationCount":12,"viewCount":1,"countAnswer":0,"countValuable":1,"persistDateTime":"2020-05-06T17:31:31"}]

Comment: Понимаете о чем я?

Comment: Это просто List<Object>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в вопросе метод, принимающий и возвращающий лист, а в комментариях 2 джейсона.не знаю, как это связано, но, поскольку я вижу конкретные примеры джейсонов в комментариях, а в вопросе некое схематическое отображение листов, то предполагаю, что все таки у вас на входе джейсон. 
раз это джейсон, а мы хотим каким-то образом работать с данными с помощью java, то мы бы хотели его распарсить и превратить в объекты. когда мы получим объекты, то с ними выполним любые преобразования.
я пользуюсь lombok, чтобы не писать гетерры, сеттеры и т.д., а также гугловым Gson, чтобы парсить джейсон(вы можете сгенерировать геттеры, сеттеры и т.д. и использовать любой другой сериализатор).
итак создадим 2 класса, в которые и будем парсить наш джейсон:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@lombok.Data
public class Response {

    private String id;    
    private String title;
    private String persistDateTime;
    private String countValuable;    
    private String viewCount;    
    private String countAnswer;
    private String username;    
    private String reputationCount;    
    private List<Tags> tags;

    public List<Tags> getTags() {
        if (tags==null) tags = new ArrayList<>();
        return tags;
    }

}

@lombok.Data
class Tags {

    private String id;    
    private String name;
    private String description;

}
```

это просто модели. коллекцию объектов Response мы и получим в результате десериализации нашего джейсона. тогда для того, чтобы распарсить наш джейсон и привести его к указанному вами виду напишем специальный метод, принимающий стринг с джейсоном и возвращающий коллекцию в нужном нам виде:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    private final static Type TYPE = new TypeToken<List<Response>>(){}.getType();  
    private final static Gson GSON = new Gson();

    public Collection transform(String json) {        
        Collection<Response> responseList = GSON.fromJson(json, TYPE);        
        Map<String, Response> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();        
        for (Response response : responseList) {
            if (result.containsKey(response.getId())) {
                result.get(response.getId()).getTags().addAll(response.getTags());
            }
            else result.put(response.getId(), response);
        }        
        return result.values();        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дмитрий спасибо за предоставленное решение - оно также имеет место быть, но я решил вопрос немного иначе:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

@Repository
public class QuestionDtoDaoImpl extends ReadWriteDaoImpl<QuestionDto, Long> implements QuestionDtoDao {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<QuestionDto> getQuestionDtoList() {
        List<QuestionDto> questionDto = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            questionDto = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT "
                    + "q.id, "
                    + "q.title, "
                    + "q.user.fullName, "
                    + "q.user.reputationCount, "
                    + "q.viewCount, "
                    + "q.countValuable, "
                    + "q.persistDateTime,  "
                    + "t.id, "
                    + "t.name, "
                    + "t.description, "
                    + "(SELECT COUNT (a) FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id), "
                    + "(SELECT a.isHelpful FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id) "
                    + "FROM Question q JOIN q.tags t")
                    .unwrap(Query.class)
                    .setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {
                        @Override
                        public Object transformTuple(Object[] objects, String[] strings) {
                            TagDto tagDto = TagDto.builder()
                                    .id((Long) objects[7])
                                    .name((String) objects[8])
                                    .description((String) objects[9])
                                    .build();
                            List<TagDto> tagDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
                            tagDtoList.add(tagDto);
                            return QuestionDto.builder()
                                    .id((Long) objects[0])
                                    .title((String) objects[1])
                                    .username((String) objects[2])
                                    .reputationCount((Integer) objects[3])
                                    .viewCount((Integer) objects[4])
                                    .countValuable((Integer) objects[5])
                                    .persistDateTime((LocalDateTime) objects[6])
                                    .tags(tagDtoList)
                                    .countAnswer(((Number) objects[10]).intValue())
                                    .isHelpful((Boolean) objects[11])
                                    .build();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public List transformList(List list) {
                            Map<Long, QuestionDto> result = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());//Comparator.naturalOrder() 
                            for (Object obj : list) {
                                QuestionDto questionDto = (QuestionDto) obj;
                                if (result.containsKey(questionDto.getId())) 
                                    result.get(questionDto.getId()).getTags().addAll(questionDto.getTags());
                                else result.put(questionDto.getId(), questionDto);
                            }
                            return new ArrayList<>(result.values());
                        }
                    })
                    .getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return questionDto;

    }
```

PS. Есть-ли возможность переписать этот код с помощью стрим?

Comment: метод transformList лучше напиишите так(ответ я исправил). в этом случае нет вложенного цикла. что касается стримов, я не уверен, что в этом случае стримы будут более читаемыми

Comment: Огромное спасибо за оптимизацию! :)

Comment: Переписал - все работает безупречно, и по таймингам стало лучше

Comment: Дмитрий а как бы сделать чтобы вывод был в обратном порядке, но с вашим кодом, я что имею ввиду чтобы самый последний вопрос прилетал первым, ну и самый старый вопрос был последним, а так получается json прилетает как в БД, а надо наоборот, в моем коде было именно наоборот

Comment: да, можно сделать реверс коллекции, ответ изменил

Comment: а с какой целью делаем реверс? вы QuestionDto сортируете по айдихе в порядке возрастания или там какой-то особый порядок?

Comment: по Id нужен порядок убывания, спасибо еще раз

Comment: в общем мне надо еще покопать коллекции что-то я подзабыл их с кора

Comment: в таком случае все можно сделать проще. поменяйте имплементацию коллекции Map на TreeMap, эта коллекция автоматически сортирует по ключу. При создании в аргументы принимается компаратор. Можно определить натуральный порядок либо обратный порядок. В класссе QuestionDto айди нужно изменить на лонг либо инт (коим эта айдиха и является), потому как сортировка по стрингу в данном случае некорретктна. я исправил ответ

Comment: Id у меня и есть Лонг, я исправил этот момент у себя сразу

Comment: тогда обновите метод transformList, который я испрвил. это будет работать быстрее и меньше ресурсов потреблять (особенно на больших коллекциях). кроме того, в этом случае вы всегда получите модели в обратном порядке относительно айди (независимо от того, как эти модели будут располагаться в листе, который передается в метод)

Comment: Дмитрий спасибо огромное! Вы настоящий Гуру Java :), я пока только учусь, но надеюсь в скором времени достигну вашего уровня ;) с вами можно как-то связываться если не через этот сайт?